# An issue about converting a pointer to char to another type pointer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Test{
   int a;
   int b;
};
int main(){
  char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*32);  //#a
  char* ptr = buffer + 4;  //#b
  new(ptr) Test;  //#c
  char* ptr2 = buffer + 4;  //#d
  Test* tptr = reinterpret_cast<Test*>(ptr2);  //#e
  tptr->a = 1; // #f
}
```

Consider the above code, at the point `#a`, the allocation function `malloc` allocates a storage region and implicitly create an array object of type `char[32]`, which is mentioned in the following rule:

> Some operations are described as implicitly creating objects within a specified region of storage. For each operation that is specified as implicitly creating objects, that operation implicitly creates and starts the lifetime of zero or more objects of implicit-lifetime types ([basic.types]) in its specified region of storage if doing so would result in the program having defined behavior. If no such set of objects would give the program defined behavior, the behavior of the program is undefined. If multiple such sets of objects would give the program defined behavior, it is unspecified which such set of objects is created.

So, the code at `#b` is well defined, because the pointer `buffer` can be considered to point to the first element of an array, it satisfies the rule [expr.add#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4). The code at `#c` is also well defined, which will construct an object of type Test at the storage to which the `ptr` points. `#d` is the same as `#b`, which is also well defined.

However, consider the code at `#e`. Now, the pointer `ptr2` points to the fourth element of the `array`(which is created by `malloc`), the element is an object of type char whose lifetime has ended due to its storage is reused by an object of type `Test`. The expression `reinterpret_cast<Test*>(ptr2)` is equivalent to `static_cast<Test*>(static_cast<void*>(ptr2))`.

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T”, where T is an object type and cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If the original pointer value represents the address A of a byte in memory and A does not satisfy the alignment requirement of T, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an object a, and there is an object b of type T (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible with a, the result is a pointer to b. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

According to the above rule, an object of type `Test` is not pointer-interconvertible with an object of type char. So, I think the result is still a pointer to an object of type char, which is the fourth element of the array, merely its lifetime has ended.

So, I wonder Does the code at `#f` have undefined behaviour due to `tptr` does not point to an object of type `Test`? Or as an opposite, Does the pointer `tptr` indeed point to the object of type `Test` and the code is well defined? If I miss some other rules, please point it out.

Comment: To me, `tptr` is the same as `ptr` which do contain a `Test` object so I think that behavior is well-defined.

Comment: @Phil1970  However, `ptr2` points to an element of array of type char, covert such a pointer to pointer to `void` is still remain the point value which points to an object of type char, then pointer of type char is not interconvertible with pointer of type `Test`, so the point value is unchanged(which means the result still points to the object of type char). This is my reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the code at `#f` have undefined behaviour due to `tptr` does not point to an object of type `Test`?

The program has undefined behavior since `#a`, because `malloc` is defined as triggering implicit object creation and returning a pointer to a suitable created object, but the set of objects which would give the rest of the program defined behavior is empty.

Comment: I don't think `#a`, `#b`,`#c`,`#d` has undefined behaviour. `#b` and `#d` are arithmetic pointer operation, as long as they point to the element of an array, that's true due to `malloc` implicitly created the array and its element(which is of type char). `#c` is ruling by [intro.object#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#3)

Comment: I don't understand what's the meaning of such sentence "the set of objects which would give the rest of the program defined behavior is empty."

Comment: @jackX _I don't understand what's the meaning of such sentence "the set of objects which would give the rest of the program defined behavior is empty."_ `malloc` can't create objects which would make both `#b` and `#f` well-defined. Anyway, even if you believe that UB is triggerd only in `#f`, everything before it still has UB because https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.abstract#5.sentence-2

Comment: However, that sentence(intro.abstract#5.sentence-2) does not say that the previous executions have undefined behaviour, it just says there's no requirement to these executions.

Comment: Do you mean that since  `#e` and `#f` have undefined behaviour, so, that operation implicitly creates and starts the lifetime of zero or more objects of implicit-lifetime types ([basic.types]) in its specified region of storage **if doing so would result in the program having defined behavior**. the sentence is false. hence  all execution associated with `#a` all have undefined behaviour?

Comment: @jackX _that sentence does not say that the previous executions have undefined behaviour, it just says there's no requirement to these executions_ Which is [the definition of undefined behavior](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/defns.undefined).

Comment: @jackX _the sentence is false. hence all execution associated with #a all have undefined behaviour?_ Something like this.

Comment: All right. However I have another question, that is , whether the `tptr` points to an object of type char or points to an object of type `Test`? if we only consider  `#e`, please ignore these previous code.

Comment: @jackX _please ignore these previous code_ Where does `ptr2` come from if we ignore everything except `#a` and `#e`?

Comment: change `#a` to `char arr[32]; char* buffer = arr;`, please consider `#e`

Comment: @jackX `buffer` points to the first element of `arr`. If you need a pointer to a `Test` object implicitly created there, you need to launder the `reinterpret_cast`-ed pointer.

Comment: So, in simple. you think the pointer `ptr2` still points to the fourth element of array, Right?

Comment: @jackX you mean `tptr`? If there is no `#f`, then yep, `ptr2` and `tptr` must point to an array element, an object of `char` type.